# how to download all the tags from delicious

Tags: web-services, tags, delicious-api

how to download all the tags from delicious, like all the tags shown in: 
http://delicious.com/tag

Comment: why? Which programming language? why are you not more elaborating what you want?

Comment: http://delicious.com/tag doesn't show all the tags, it just shows the 200 or so most popular ones.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to get *all* tags, you can get all tags for your username (replace the placeholders with your username and password):

```
curl https://{username}:{password}@api.del.icio.us/v1/tags/get
```

This returns some XML which (for me) looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<tags>
  <tag count="42" tag=".Net"/>
  <tag count="9" tag="AI"/>
  <tag count="1" tag="ASP"/>
  <tag count="64" tag="Accessibility"/>
  <tag count="15" tag="Admin"/>
  <tag count="3" tag="Agile"/>
  <tag count="57" tag="Ajax"/>
  <tag count="12" tag="Amiga"/>
  ...
</tags>
```

Or you can get a list of recommended or suggested tags for a particular URL:

```
curl https://{username}:{password}@api.del.icio.us/v1/posts/suggest?url=http://stackoverflow.com/
```

This returns XML with two different types of tag, your tags which are recommended plus tags from all users which are popular:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suggest>
  <recommended>Reference</recommended>
  <recommended>Development</recommended>
  <recommended>Software</recommended>
  <recommended>Tips</recommended>
  <recommended>Community</recommended>
  <recommended>Technology</recommended>
  <recommended>HowTo</recommended>
  <recommended>Forum</recommended>
  <recommended>Web2.0</recommended>
  <recommended>Blog</recommended>
  <recommended>Learning</recommended>
  <recommended>FAQ</recommended>
  <popular>programming</popular>
  <popular>reference</popular>
  <popular>development</popular>
  <popular>software</popular>
  <popular>tips</popular>
</suggest>
```

There's a webmonkey article which covers [using the Delicious API from PHP](http://www.webmonkey.com/tutorial/Using_the_Delicious_API).

Comment: Any way to specify the language for the suggested tags ?

Comment: @Gilbou Not that I'm aware of

Answer (score 0):

If you mean your own tags, then the easiest solution is to use the [Export feature](https://secure.delicious.com/settings/profile/export) on its web site. I guess you can automate this (including authentication) via `curl`, `wget` or something similar.